# Socket.IO giving constant polling 404 error (Socket.IO new user)

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Im using a Express server and trying to implement Socket.io for the first time, and I keep getting this whenever I open it:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OKgNATB 404 0.526 ms - 149
GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OKgNBww 404 0.332 ms - 149
GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OKgNDOV 404 0.411 ms - 149
```

app.ts:

```
 import express from 'express';
 import morgan from 'morgan';
 import favicon from 'serve-favicon';
 import path from 'path';
 import cors from 'cors';
 
 import { errorManager } from './middlewares/errors_middleware.js';
 import { ordersRouter } from './routers/OrdersRouter.js';
 import { usersRouter } from './routers/UsersRouter.js';
 
 import { createServer } from 'http';
 import { Server } from 'socket.io';

 export const app = express();
 const httpServer = createServer(app);
 const io = new Server(httpServer, {
 cors: {
 origin: '*',
     },
 });
 
 io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 console.log('HELLO');
 });
 
 app.use(favicon(path.join('.', 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
 app.use(cors());
 app.use(morgan('dev'));
 app.use(express.json());
 
 app.get('/', (_req, res, next) => {
 res.send('H');
 next();
 });
 
 Routers
 app.use('/orders', ordersRouter);
 app.use('/users', usersRouter);
 
 app.use(errorManager);
```

index.ts:

```
 import http from 'http';
 import createDebug from 'debug';
 import { app } from './app.js';
 import { dbConnect } from './dbconnect/dbconnect.js';
 
 const debug = createDebug('StoryLine:INDEX');
 
 const port = 3300;
 const server = http.createServer(app);
 
 server.on('listening', () => {
 const addr = server.address();
 if (addr === null) return;
 let bind: string;
 if (typeof addr === 'string') {
 bind = 'pipe ' + addr;
 else {
 bind =
 addr.address === '::'
                 ? `http://localhost:${addr?.port}`
                 : `port ${addr?.port}`;
     }
 debug(`SERVER: Listening on: ${bind}`);
 });
 
 server.on('error', (error: Error, response: http.ServerResponse) => {
 response.write(error.message);
 response.end();
 });
 
 dbConnect()
     .then((mongoose) => {
 debug(
             'Database connection -> SUCCESSFUL: ',
 mongoose.connection.db.databaseName
         );
 server.listen(port);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
 debug('Database connection -> COULD NOT CONNECT');
 server.emit(error);
     });
```

I simply want to get a console.log telling me that a user is connecting. I have tried following the Socket.io docs for express but its not working for me.